# Connection Resiliency in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I am working on an Asp.Net Core 1.0 + EF Core 1.0 (RC2 targeting `net46`) project which will be deployed in Azure and relying on SQL Azure for data.

I know that EF Core 1.0 doesn't plan to support [Connection Resiliency for v1.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap#critical-orm-features)

1. Is it possible to support connection resiliency through some other means?
2. [.Net 4.5.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/10/17/net-framework-4-5-1-rtm-start-coding/) added built-in support for connection resiliency in ADO.NET. Since EF is built on top of ADO.NET does it mean that it's already included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of improvements in that area in .net 4,6,1, but true Command execution resiliency is still on th EF Core roadmap

Comment: Thanks EricEJ. How does Command Execution resiliency differ from Connection Resiliency?

Comment: The Connection resiliency feature in .net only kicks in when opening a connection, not when executing a command.

Comment: I see. Do you think there's a way achieving this via EF command interception or something..